# Estimating time varying parameters of ODE with the help of solution data

Tags: machine-learning, parameterization, differential-equations

I am trying to extend a parameter estimation of ODE model from constant parameter estimation to time-varying parameter estimation. I have completed the constant parameter estimation (where parameter is kept constant throughout the time); the implementation is as follows:

**Mathematical background of ODE:**

The ODE which I am solving is a system of 3 variables [S,I,R]; Which is to model a epidemic ; The S, I and R represents Susceptible, Infected and Recovered individuals from a disease.

The constants; 'beta' and 'gamma' represents the infectivity rate and 'recovery-rate' respectively. At the moment they are assumed constant for the whole time-span in my code. But I wish to find a time-varying 'beta' and 'gamma'.

**Statistical motivation:**

The time-varying 'beta' and 'gamma' means; that the nature of the disease changes with time and hence these parameters should also change.

Phenomenas like; public restriction, vaccination, lock-downs etc; change the nature of the observed values of [S,I,R], and hence we want to record these changes in our parameters 'beta' and 'gamma' as a function of time.

**Code:**

(a) Define the ODE model of SIR with cosntant parameter 'beta' and 'gamma'

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


I0, R0 = 0.10798003802281400, 0.0020386203150461700
S0 = 1 - I0 - R0
t = np.linspace(0, 146, 146)

# The SIR model differential equations.
def deriv(y, t, beta, gamma):
    S, I, R = y
    dSdt = -beta * S * I 
    dIdt = beta * S * I  - gamma * I
    dRdt = gamma * I
    return dSdt, dIdt, dRdt

I_d = x[:,1] # from dataset, we will finally try to fit the SIR plot with this data
```

(b) Define fn(x) for minimising the loss with respect to the data of 'I'

```
def fn(x):
    # parameters unwrapped
    beta, gamma = x;   
    I0, R0 = 0.10798003802281400, 0.0020386203150461700
    S0 = 1 - I0 - R0
    y0 = S0, I0, R0

    ret = odeint(deriv, y0, t_d, args=(beta, gamma))
    S, I, R = ret.T
    error = sum((I-I_d)*(I-I_d))
    
    return error

# initialise with current best guess
init_x = [0.1, 0.05]

res = minimize(fn, init_x, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-8)

fn(res.x) # calculate final error
res.x # calculate final parameters
```

(c) Finally we obtain a constant 'beta' and delta' values for the full time-span.

**Question:**

1. I want to extend this model to a time varying beta and delta. Is it
   possible to estimate parameters like that?
2. Do I need to assume some conditions on 'beta' and 'delta' such that
   I can run the optimisation; conditions like lets 'beta' and 'delta'
   follow a linear equation; such as '**beta**' = a1(t) + b1 and
   '**delta**' = a2(t) + b2. and then find the co-efficients
   a1,a2,b1,b2 ?

Comment: Hi! Could you give some mathematical details of your PDE ? Also, what is the statistical motivation behind it?

Comment: Sure, I'll update the question.